# 'float' object is not callable. Option Pricing

Tags: python, function, numpy, scipy

The script I was using gives following errors. I thought that the error might be with the float of `np.inf` but tried using `np.iinfo(np.int32).max`, but it didn't do anything. I have no one to consult with so asking here.

```
def BCC_call_value(S0,K,T,r,kappa_v,theta_v,sigma_v,rho,v0,lamb,mu,delta):
    int_value=quad(lambda u:BCC_int_func(u,S0,K,T,r,kappa_v,theta_v,sigma_v,rho,v0,lamb,mu,delta),0,np.inf,limit=250)[0]
    call_value=max(0,S0-np.exp(-r*T)*np.sqrt(S0*K)/np.pi*int_value)
    return call_value

def BCC_int_func(u,S0,K,T,r,kappa_v,theta_v,sigma_v,rho,v0,lamb,mu,delta):
    '''Valuation of European call option in BCC97 model via Lewis (2001)
    Fourier-based approach:integration function.

    Parameter definitions see function BCC_call_value.'''
    char_func_value=BCC_char_func(u-1j*0.5,T,r,kappa_v,theta_v,sigma_v,rho,v0,lamb,mu,delta)
    int_func_value=1/(u**2+0.25)*(np.exp(1j*u*np.log(S0/K))*char_func_value).real
    return int_func_value

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-874d91836da1> in <module>
----> 1 BCC_call_value(S0,K,T,r,kappa_v,theta_v,sigma_v,rho,v0,lamb,mu,delta)

<ipython-input-3-02bea979d7ba> in BCC_call_value(S0, K, T, r, kappa_v, theta_v, sigma_v, rho, v0, lamb, mu, delta)
     68 
     69     '''
---> 70     int_value=quad(lambda u:BCC_int_func(u,S0,K,T,r,kappa_v,theta_v,sigma_v,rho,v0,lamb,mu,delta),0,np.inf,limit=250)[0]
     71     call_value=max(0,S0-np.exp(-r*T)*np.sqrt(S0*K)/np.pi*int_value)
     72     return call_value

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    339     if weight is None:
    340         retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
--> 341                        points)
    342     else:
    343         retval = _quad_weight(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel,

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    448             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    449         else:
--> 450             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    451     else:
    452         if infbounds != 0:

<ipython-input-3-02bea979d7ba> in <lambda>(u)
     68 
     69     '''
---> 70     int_value=quad(lambda u:BCC_int_func(u,S0,K,T,r,kappa_v,theta_v,sigma_v,rho,v0,lamb,mu,delta),0,np.inf,limit=250)[0]
     71     call_value=max(0,S0-np.exp(-r*T)*np.sqrt(S0*K)/np.pi*int_value)
     72     return call_value

<ipython-input-3-02bea979d7ba> in BCC_int_func(u, S0, K, T, r, kappa_v, theta_v, sigma_v, rho, v0, lamb, mu, delta)
    144 
    145     Parameter definitions see function BCC_call_value.'''
--> 146     char_func_value=BCC_char_func(u-1j*0.5,T,r,kappa_v,theta_v,sigma_v,rho,v0,lamb,mu,delta)
    147     int_func_value=1/(u**2+0.25)*(np.exp(1j*u*np.log(S0/K))*char_func_value).real
    148     return int_func_value

<ipython-input-3-02bea979d7ba> in BCC_char_func(u, T, r, kappa_v, theta_v, sigma_v, rho, v0, lamb, mu, delta)
    167 
    168     Parameter definitions see function BCC_call_value.'''
--> 169     BCC1=H93_char_func(u,T,r,kappa_v,theta_v,sigma_v,rho,v0)
    170     BCC2=M76_char_func(u,T,lamb,mu,delta)
    171     return BCC1 * BCC2

<ipython-input-3-02bea979d7ba> in H93_char_func(u, T, r, kappa_v, theta_v, sigma_v, rho, v0)
    179     c2=-np.sqrt((rho*sigma_v*u*1j-kappa_v)**2-sigma_v**2*(-u*1j-u**2))
    180     c3=(kappa_v-rho*sigma_v*u*1j+c2)/(kappa_v-rho*sigma_v*u*1j-c2)
--> 181     H1=(r*u*1j*T(c1/sigma_v**2)*((kappa_v-rho*sigma_v*u*1j+c2)*T-2*np.log((1-c3*np.exp(c2*T))/(1-c3))))
    182     H2=((kappa_v - rho*sigma_v*u*1j+c2)/sigma_v**2*((1-np.exp(c2*T))/(1-c3*np.exp(c2*T))))
    183     char_func_value=np.exp(H1+H2*v0)

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: Aside: that code is very difficult to read. You're allowed (and encouraged) to make judicious use of whitespace to aid in readability. Compare `call_value=max(0,S0-np.exp(-r*T)*np.sqrt(S0*K)/np.pi*int_value)` and `call_value = max(0, S0 - np.exp(-r * T) * np.sqrt(S0 * K) / np.pi * int_value)`, where I simply added a few spaces. Newlines can really help, too.

Comment: What is `T` in `H93_char_func`? `T(c1/sigma_v**2)` doesn't look right, especially considering you appear to use `T` as a number later in that same line: `... * T - 2 * ...`

Comment: At some point you have `variable(...)`, where `variable` is a `float` (and it is likely that you want `variable*(...)` ).

Comment: Thanks, I will make note of using more spaces for readability) 
And you were right abt the T, I missed the "+" in between. It was supposed to be T+(c1/sigma_v**2). 
I feel so freaking stupid for not checking the code more thoroughly.... 
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `H93_char_func`:

```py
H1=(r*u*1j*T(c1/sigma_v**2)*((kappa_v-rho*sigma_v*u*1j+c2)*T-2*np.log((1-c3*np.exp(c2*T))/(1-c3))))
#          ^ here you attempt to call T...                 ^ here you use it as a number
```

Is `T` meant to be a function or a number? From context I think it's a number, which means you need to change `T(c1 / sigma_v ** 2)` to whatever it's meant to be (maybe `T * (c1 / sigma_v ** 2)`?).

I also *strongly* recommend adding whitespace and maybe a variable or two to hold intermediate results. This is very hard to read.